# WinApi удалить графические компоненты из "чужого" окна

Tags: c#, c++, c, windows, winapi

Например, я знаю ID процесса в Windows.

Вопрос в следующем: могу ли я используя winapi удалить(скрыть, оставить визуально, но сделать не активными) некоторые графические элементы окна другого приложения, например кнопку или поле ввода?

В моем случае мне нужно удалить из окна Ms Word вот этот элемент окна
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: >"могу ли я из своего приложения..." . В вашем случае "MS Word" - не ваше приложение :D  Поделитесь, если не секрет, кто вам дал такую задачу?

Comment: Чисто теоретически должно сработать. Надо попробовать послать этим элементам ShowWindow(SW_HIDE). По ИД процесса вы можете получить все окна процесса и для каждого окна получить список дочерних, потом найти среди них свой лейбл и спинбокс и послать им сообщение)

Comment: "могу ли я из своего приложения..."  - Я имею в виду написать свою программу, на C#, С++ не суть, которое бы использовало winapi и удалило бы графический элемент в другом приложении например winword.exe

Comment: Удалить совсем (т.е. чтобы попытка их задействовать положила программу) или просто скрыть?

Comment: Хотя-бы скрыть или сделать неактивными

Comment: Для приложений, использующих стандартные диалоговые окна можно, используйте [FindWindowEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363167/how-can-i-get-the-child-windows-of-a-window-given-its-hwnd) + EnumWindows + ShowWindow. Для приложений, использующих WPF или DirectUI, скорее всего ничего не выйдет.